# MATLAB: Nonlinear fitting with MultiStart finds local but not global minimum

Tags: matlab, optimization, data-fitting

I'm fitting a function to some nonlinear data. However, the output that I get is:

```
Attempt to execute SCRIPT MultiStart as a function:
/MATLAB Drive/Amsterdam/2 Fitting/MultiStart.m

Error in MultiStart (line 42)
ms = MultiStart('PlotFcn',@gsplotbestf);
```

This is my code. I've specified the parameters, the initial values, the objective function and the bounds. My code does find a local minimum, but then can't find the global one.

```
function [EPSC, IPSC, CPSC, t] = generate_current(G_max_chl, G_max_glu, EGlu, EChl, Vm, tau_rise_In, tau_decay_In, tau_rise_Ex, tau_decay_Ex,tmax)
    
    dt = 0.1;                               % time step duration (ms)
    t = 0:dt:tmax-dt;
    
    % Compute compound current
    
    IPSC = ((G_max_chl) .* ((1 - exp(-t / tau_rise_In)) .* exp(-t / tau_decay_In)) * (Vm - EChl));
    
    EPSC = ((G_max_glu) .* ((1 - exp(-t / tau_rise_Ex)) .* exp(-t / tau_decay_Ex)) * (Vm - EGlu));
    
    CPSC = IPSC + EPSC;
    
end
```

After generating the data with the previous function, I have the fitting procedure:

```
% Simulated data
[~,~,CPSC,t] = generate_current(80,15,0,-70,-30,0.44,15,0.73,3,120);

% % Parameters
G_max_chl = 80;                          % Maximal conductance of Chl
G_max_glu = 15;                          % Maximal conductance of Glu
tau_rise_Ex = 0.73;                      % Tau rise for E
tau_rise_In = 0.44;                      % Tau rise for I
tau_decay_Ex = 3;                        % Tau decay for E
tau_decay_In = 15;                       % Tau decay for I

p = [G_max_chl,  G_max_glu, tau_rise_In, tau_decay_In, tau_rise_Ex, tau_decay_Ex];

dt = 0.1;
tmax = 121;
t = 1:0.1:tmax-dt;
Vm = -30;
EGlu = 0;
EChl = -70;

% Create the objective function
fitfcn = @(p, t, Vm, EGlu, EChl) ((p(1)) .* ((1 - exp(-t / p(3))) .* exp(-t / p(4))) * (Vm - EChl)) + ((p(2)) .* ((1 - exp(-t / p(5))) .* exp(-t / p(6))) * (Vm - EGlu));

preal = [80,15,0.44,0.73,15,3]; % Real coefficients

xdata = t;
ydata = CPSC; % Response data with noise

% Set bounds and initial point.
lb = [0,0,0,0,0,0];
ub = [150,150,5,5,20,20];
p0 = [50,50,1,1,1,1]; % Arbitrary initial points

% Find the best local fit
[xfitted,errorfitted] = lsqcurvefit(@(p,t)fitfcn(p, t, Vm, EGlu, EChl), p0, xdata, ydata,lb,ub)

%Set up the problem for MultiStart.
problem = createOptimProblem('lsqcurvefit','x0',p0,'objective',fitfcn,...
    'lb',lb,'ub',ub,'xdata',xdata,'ydata',ydata);

% Find a global solution
ms = MultiStart('PlotFcn',@gsplotbestf);
[xmulti,errormulti] = run(ms,problem,200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a script called `MultiStart.m` in the location `/MATLAB Drive/Amsterdam/2 Fitting`, which is in Matlab's search path. When you call `MultiStart()`, Matlab assumes that you are calling this script instead of the built-in `MultiStart` function.

You need to rename the script to something that does not conflict with Matlab's built-in function names or, alternatively, [remove](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rmpath.html) `/MATLAB Drive/Amsterdam/2 Fitting` from Matlab's search path.